# Cyclic counter with constant Hamming distance

Tags: algorithms, hamiltonian-path

For what "n" counts are there cyclic counters with constant Hamming distance "d"?

(In particular, what if "d" == 1?)

EDIT:

Let me show the problem through examples.

The 3-bit Gray counter is well known. Its 8 consecutive states are:

```
000
001
011
010
110
111
101
100
```

However, you can also create shorter Hamming-1 counters (6 state):

```
000
001
011
010
110
100
```

or (6 state):

```
000
001
011
111
110
100
```

or (4 state):

```
001
011
111
101
```

The questions are:

- for any "n" states, how to tell if there is a cyclic counter with Hamming distance "d"?
- how to systematically generate such a counter (or sequence of states).

Comment: Your $5$-state counter doesn't work: `011` and `110` are Hamming distance $2$ apart.

Comment: True. I have removed that, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When $d=1$ and our states have $k$ bits, you can create cyclic counters of any length $n$ where $n$ is even and $n \le 2^k$.

(Odd lengths $n$ are not possible, because we always alternate between an odd number and an even number of `1`s in any counter, so we must take an even number of steps to return to the start.)

To do this, start with a Gray counter of length $2^{k-1}$ using $k-1$ bits. For example, when $k=4$, we have

```
000 001 011 010 110 111 101 100
```

To get a cyclic counter of length $n$ using $k$ bits ($n=10$ in the example below) we take the first $\frac n2$ of these states, with a $0$ appended...

```
0000 0010 0110 0100 1100 ...
```

and then the same $\frac n2$ states, with a $1$ appended, in reverse order:

```
0000 0010 0110 0100 1100 1101 0101 0111 0011 0001
```

This is the cyclic counter we wanted.